# Hallow and corruption troubles

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I need some help on my terraria world...

So basically I'm trying to contain the corruption and hallow but underground they've spread. I tried to do the three block gap however underground the hallow and corruption merge so there's no where to dig.

I don't particularly want my whole world to be one biome so if anyone has any recommendations could you please comment bellow and tell me what you think. :/

Comment: @TheCodingMonster What are you talking about? This seems like a perfectly valid question, alotugh possibly a duplicate. Also, not related to Minecraft in any ways.

Comment: I'd use the Clentaminator

Comment: The last line is asking for comments. About minecraft, sorry my bad I will edit the comment

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Arqade is not a gaming forum, but a place for answers. If you want recommendations, go to somewhere like Terraria Forums. Also, do not ask a question for comments, ask a question for answers

Answer (score 1):

The three-block gap includes diagonals; it's easy to miss what are effectively 2-block gaps.  Hardmode corruption is perfectly capable of bridging this gap:

[image: diagram of corruption spread, including an unholy arrow :)]

Purification/Vile Powder, or the Clentaminator and Green Solution, can push back alignment biomes, but you'll need to eliminate "bridges" like this from your isolation trenches.

Also, above the datum, corrupt grass can sprout thorny bushes that spread corruption.

Answer (score 0):

> The Hallow cannot convert mud or jungle grass. [Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Hallow)

However it spreads through dirt and normal grass. Contain the hallow by planting jungle grass around it, however keep in mind that other biomes can take over jungle grass.

Also: [Guide:Containing the Hallow/Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Containing_the_Hallow/Corruption#The_Hallow)

Answer (score -2):

It takes a day for it to stop and it will stop when it gets to 5% of your world.